# REST API: Can we use plural naming for queries?

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions

Say we want to send a list of client IDs to some endpoint. Should we use the name "client" or "clients" for the query? I think both cases have pros and cons, but is there some convention for this?

```
GET https://somedomain.com/some/endpoint?client(s)=1&client(s)=2
```

Comment: Use common sense: if you allow a list of client id's `clients` makes sense. If you want one parameter per client id it should be `client`.

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.  Any information encoded into the identifier is done at the discretion of the server and for its own exclusive use.

Part of the reason for this: as the server, you want to be able to change how you encode information into the URI to make it work better for your infrastructure.

For example, if you were working with an query string parsing library that could automatically handle list arguments, provided that they matched some particular pattern, then you would want to be able to take advantage of that.

So the spelling conventions for query parameters is a local choice; very similar to the way that the spellings of variable names in code is a local choice.